# How to set minikube to auto start on windows log on?

Tags: windows, minikube

How I can set minikube to auto start on windows 10 login? I checked but I can't find anything on google.

I saw that there is a default parameter `autostart-enabled=off` but I dont know where I can set it.

At the moment after I restart my pc I can see in Hyper-V Manager that the minikube machine is running but when I try minikube dashboard in terminal I get:

> minikube is not currently running so the service cannot be accessed

Answer (score 5):

Should the normal startup functionality of w10 work?

> To change which apps run at startup, press and hold (or right-click) the Start  button, select Task Manager, and then select the Startup tab. Choose an app, then select Enable or Disable.
>
> To add or remove an app from the Startup tab, press the Windows Logo Key  + R, type shell:startup, and then select OK. This opens the Startup folder. Select Start . Find the app you're looking to add or remove, and press and hold (or right-click) it. Select More > Open File Location. In the file location folder, press and hold (or right-click) the app and select Copy. Paste the shortcut to your app into the Startup folder to have it run at startup.

Info from:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026268/windows-change-startup-apps-in-windows-10

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @mico but I already knew how  I can add a service to auto start on windows logon. I thought that minikube had a parameter for this as i already included in my question (autostart-enabled=off) but I don’t know how I can change it

Comment: Actually there is an issue rising when Docker Desktop is not fully initialized at that time and `minikube start` fails, I wonder if there would be a way to wait for docker/kubernetes to start before launching minikube

Answer (score 2):

You could create a bat script `minikube start` and add it as a scheduled job that start on start up of windows